# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined in Angular4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular4-forms

I've developed a simple mean stack application for CRUD functionalities. Now my back-end is working correctly i.e its posting data to MongoDB but the front-end seems to give me an issue that says:

```
    ERROR Type Error: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
        at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EmployeeComponent.html:4)
        at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10846)
        at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10243)
        at callViewAction (core.js:10484)
        at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10426)
        at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10249)
        at callViewAction (core.js:10484)
        at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10426)
        at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10249)
        at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11136)
```

This error is encountered at:-

```
  <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
    <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._id">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name">
        <label>Name :
          <label class="red-text">*</label>
        </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are retriving the data from api asynchronously, handle the null data with an *ngIf check as follows,

```
 <form *ngIf="employeeService?.selectedEmployee?" #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
    <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._id">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name">
        <label>Name :
          <label class="red-text">*</label>
        </label>
```

Comment: thank you for the feed back!. but i've managed to solve my difficulty. altho ur answer was correct i think  the problem was that i hadn;t enable cors origin as im using Nodejs for the back-end.  so angular could'nt recognise the ids as it was'nt configured with node

Comment: Perfect solution, Thanks @Sajeetharan